# PassportJS Validates Expired JWT

Tags: javascript, jwt, passport.js

the crux of my issue is that **PassportJS appears to be validating a JWT which should be invalid as the current time exceeds the exp parameter**.

I have provided the relevant code snippets and an explaination of what I *think* should be happening (although it clearly isn't!!)

## The code

```
// In server.js
// ...
const passport = require("passport");
// ...

require("./config/passport")(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());

// ...
```

```
// In token.js (used to issue JWT)
const jsonwebtoken = require("jsonwebtoken");
// ...

const issueJWT = (user) => {
  const _id = user._id;
  const expiresIn = 30000; // 30s for testing purposes
  const payload = {
    sub: _id,
    iat: Date.now(),
  };

  const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, {
    expiresIn: expiresIn,
    algorithm: "RS256",
  });

  return {
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
    expires: expiresIn,
  };
};
```

```
// In passport.js
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
// ...

const options = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: PUB_KEY,
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
};

module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.sub }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false);
        }
      });
    })
  );
};
```

```
// In routes.js
// ...
const passport = require("passport");
const { authenticateWithAccessToken } = require("../controllers/usersController");
// ...
router
  .route("/authenticate-with-access-token")
  .get(
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    authenticateWithAccessToken
  );
```

```
// In usersController.js
exports.authenticateWithAccessToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = req.user;

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

### Sample payload

```
{
 alg: "RS256",
 typ: "JWT"
}.
{
 sub: "5eec9f1c4a416c1e50fc0a8e", // user._id
 iat: 1593258411458,              // 2020-06-27 11:46:51
 exp: 1593258441458               // 2020-06-27 11:47:21
}.
[signature]
```

### What I would expect to happen

1. Client sends GET request to /authenticate-with-access-token with Bearer token (JWT) in auth header
2. PassportJS (via `jsonwebtoken.verify()`) attempts to verify JWT but finds that `Date.now()` exceeds the expiry on the JWT
3. PassportJS raises an error, resolving the request with a 401 Unauthorized response

### What does happen

1. Client sends GET request to /authenticate-with-access-token with Bearer token (JWT) in auth header
2. PassportJS passes the user object into the request body and calls `next()`
3. Final piece of middleware runs, resolving the request with a 200 OK response and passes the user details back via a JSON body

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but for the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out!

Turns out (from looking at examples on the jsonwebtoken documentation) that the iat property used when signing the token should be in seconds rather than miliseconds. Therefore the `Date.now()` in tokens.js should actually be `Math.floor(Date.now / 1000)`:

```
// In token.js (used to issue JWT)
const jsonwebtoken = require("jsonwebtoken");
// ...

const issueJWT = (user) => {
  const _id = user._id;
  const expiresIn = 30; // 30s for testing purposes

  const payload = {
    sub: _id,
    iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
  };

  const signedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, {
    expiresIn: expiresIn,
    algorithm: "RS256",
  });

  return {
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
    expires: expiresIn,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the `Maxage` of the `jwt` token in the `options` object
since passport is verifying the token using `jsonwebtoken` module, also if you set the `ignoreExpiration` option to true passport will not validate the expritation of the token, I know this is not the case because I can't see it in your code, but my best guess is that you have to set `Maxage` in your options like this `{ expiresIn: '1h' }`

from the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/)

> jsonWebTokenOptions: passport-jwt is verifying the token using jsonwebtoken. Pass here an options object for any other option you can pass the jsonwebtoken verifier. (i.e maxAge)

if you wanna learn more about the [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have just added the code which generates the JWT to my question and you can see that I am setting expiresIn to 30000 (30s for testing). Is this what you meant?

Comment: I also tried adding the maxAge property to the function call and that did not help either.